# Measuring ones mathematics ability regularly - how to avoid getting better at the tests

Tags: testing, test-design

This question might not suit the site, if so I apologise.

I'd like to regularly test my maths skills, essentially finding out if I'm getting better or worse at a maths in general and then plot the data. The rational behind this is I'd like to find out if things like regular exercise, changes to diet, etc. make a measurable different *to me*.

My concern is although there are ways of testing my analytical and mathematics abilities using some form of test, whatever test I use I will inevitably get better *at taking the test* outside of any changes I make to my diet etc.

The only method I can think of to work around this is to make no changes for some length of time, and test myself during this period, thereby being able to identify the degree to which I get better just by taking the tests multiple times - but this is flawed because it's unlikely to be a linear process.

I understand the standard for this is to have multiple test subjects and a control group, but can someone do this type of work alone?

Comment: Why don't you just drink some tea and take a stroll, it would do you better for you than taking tests again and again. Note, that I am not against testing per se like some people are, I just think that unless you consider yourself a piece of software, there is no need to take it too seriously.

Comment: @RustyCore I think maybe I didn't explain why I'm  doing this all that well. I'd like to be better at maths, but ultimately I'm doing this to see if these things really have an effect on me. I'm sure in some grand study with thousands of participants they have an effect on average, but that doesn't mean they have the same magnitude of effect for everyone. This is more about the journey than the destination.

Comment: I don't see how this can be measured. If I work on certain real analysis topics ([Example 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905487/13130) and [Example 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677914/13130)), then I'm good with certain real analysis topics but not with integration techniques. If I work on [integration techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2734220/13130), then I'm good at that but get rusty with real analysis topics. If I work on [generalized topology notions](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343400/15780), then I'm rusty with both real analysis stuff and with integration methods.

Comment: The following are related to my previous comment, which I had to verbally compress to be within the maximum character count (I think I managed to have exactly 0 characters remaining), and which at that earlier time I didn't have time to look these up: [I keep forgetting what I've learned. Should I even consider pursuing advanced degree in math?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/41838/49593) *AND* [I feel like I forgot my simple mathematical knowledge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90050/49593) **(continued)**

Comment: *AND* [How can I not forget university mathematics?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/118728/49593) *AND* [What to do if you forgot some proofs while writing your thesis?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108848/49593) *AND* [A good way to retain mathematical understanding?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748197/13130) *AND* [Formerly good at math, but after 12 years I've lost most of my skills. Now I need them once again. Any advice to grow them back?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23566/13130)

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question!

One option could be testing the **quality of how** you do math, for example:

1. Count how many careless mistakes you are making when doing maths that you usually do;
2. Measure how long you can stay focused doing maths while you are still productive and you are not easily distracted.

I think the interventions you mention enhance your cognitive ability in general, and consequently you are capable of learning more maths and focus longer on more challenging problems, thus your mathematical ability improves.

These measures also allow you to set the process of testing easier and more aligned with the goals you want to achieve in mathematics. For example, to measure focusing time you could just read maths books you would like to read anyway and stop the timer the first time you get distracted from the book.